# Unity3D ignores basic cube as particle system mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

I intend to use a particle system in my game object in Unity3D v5.3.5.

Following a tutorial, I learned I should set the *Render Mode* to *Mesh* and select an appropriate mesh.

[image]

[image]

I chose the *default cube mesh*, ***yet my particles are the exact same size and form*** as my game object that has the particle system.

[image]

What should I modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *scale settings* of the main object was applied to the particle system as well.

I removed the particle system and created an empty object with the same particle settings and a scale of {1,1,1} so the particles are cube shaped now.